# Tree.js Rookie Function not found error in BufferGeometry

Tags: typescript, three.js, svelte, sveltekit

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import * as THREE from 'three';

    var scene: THREE.Scene;
    var camera: THREE.Camera;
    var renderer: THREE.Renderer;
    let canvasElement: HTMLCanvasElement;

    const curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(0, 0, 10, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false, 0);

    onMount(() => {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, canvas: canvasElement });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(curve.getPoints(100));
        const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x3f3f46 });
        const ellipse = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);

        scene.add(ellipse);

        camera.position.z = 10;

        animate();
    });

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
</script>
```

This is the code snippet for my code in svelte component. I wrote it from the official document but running it gives an error
[error shown by the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scmo0.png)

I tried logging the object and it doesn't show any function named setFromPoints, lost at this point

Comment: What version of `three.js` are you using?

Comment: @Mugen87 it's the latest one, r149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I replicated this in svelte REPL and it works perfectly.
The only thing I did is bind `canvasElement` to an actual DOM canvas element, which you probably just omitted to do while implementing this.

See this [REPL link.](https://svelte.dev/repl/52d0aaa7748342f38f58e913bdf51202?version=3.55.1)

Comment: Well thanks, but i did binded it, my bad i guess, but now it just works fine somehow, maybe restarting server fixed it.